# rtags build is failing (due to wrong/no architecture?)

Tags: linux, cmake, compilation, include, rtags

I am trying to build rtags-2.38 on a VirtualBox Ubuntu. The `cmake` setup process runs seemingly ok:

```
VirtualBox-Ubuntu:~/Downloads/rtags-2.38$ ./configure --cmake-argument -DZLIB_LIBRARY=$ZLIB_LIBRARY --cmake-argument -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=$ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR 
Running cmake:
"cmake" "." -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1 "-DZLIB_LIBRARY=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rsyslog/lmzlibw.so" "-DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-37/include/"

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- llvm-config executable found: /usr/bin/llvm-config
-- Using Clang version 10.0.0 from /usr/lib/llvm-10/lib with CXXFLAGS -I/usr/lib/llvm-10/include -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
-- Found LibClang: /usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/libclang.so  
-- Performing Test LIBCLANG_COMPILES
-- Performing Test LIBCLANG_COMPILES - Success
-- Performing Test CXX_11_EXTENDED_REGEX_SUPPORT
-- Performing Test CXX_11_EXTENDED_REGEX_SUPPORT - Success
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Looking for backtrace
-- Looking for backtrace - found
-- Looking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW
-- Looking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW - found
-- Looking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC
-- Looking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC - found
-- Looking for mach_absolute_time
-- Looking for mach_absolute_time - not found
-- Looking for inotify_init
-- Looking for inotify_init - found
-- Looking for kqueue
-- Looking for kqueue - not found
-- Looking for epoll_wait
-- Looking for epoll_wait - found
-- Looking for select
-- Looking for select - found
-- Looking for FD_CLOEXEC
-- Looking for FD_CLOEXEC - found
-- Looking for SO_NOSIGPIPE
-- Looking for SO_NOSIGPIPE - not found
-- Looking for MSG_NOSIGNAL
-- Looking for MSG_NOSIGNAL - found
-- Looking for GetLogicalProcessorInformation
-- Looking for GetLogicalProcessorInformation - not found
-- Looking for SCHED_IDLE
-- Looking for SCHED_IDLE - found
-- Looking for SHM_DEST
-- Looking for SHM_DEST - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_STATMTIM
-- Performing Test HAVE_STATMTIM - Success
-- Found ZLIB: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rsyslog/lmzlibw.so  
-- Found OpenSSL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so (found version "1.1.1f")  
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX11
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX11 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRING_ITERATOR_ERASE
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRING_ITERATOR_ERASE - Success
-- Found emacs version 26.3
-- The following OPTIONAL packages have been found:

 * ZLIB
 * OpenSSL
 * PkgConfig, helper tool, <https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/>
   We use it to get the bash completion installation path, and replace the prefix with the value of CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.

-- The following REQUIRED packages have been found:

 * LibClang

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/mark/Downloads/rtags-2.38
VirtualBox-Ubuntu:~/Downloads/rtags-2.38$
```

Then however, things go wrong on a very basic level it seems:

```
VirtualBox-Ubuntu:~/Downloads/rtags-2.38$ make all
[  1%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/rct.dir/rct/rct/AES256CBC.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/local_lim.h:38,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/posix1_lim.h:161,
                 from /usr/include/limits.h:183,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/limits.h:194,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/syslimits.h:7,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/limits.h:34,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:14,
                 from /home/mark/Downloads/rtags-2.38/src/rct/rct/AES256CBC.cpp:6:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/xopen_lim.h:99:6: error: missing binary operator before token "("
   99 | # if INT_MAX == 32767
      |      ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/xopen_lim.h:102:7: error: missing binary operator before token "("
  102 | #  if INT_MAX == 2147483647
      |       ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/xopen_lim.h:126:6: error: missing binary operator before token "("
  126 | # if LONG_MAX == 2147483647
      |      ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-37/include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-37/include/linux/stat.h:19,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/statx.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h:446,
                 from /home/mark/Downloads/rtags-2.38/src/rct/rct/Path.h:12,
                 from /home/mark/Downloads/rtags-2.38/src/rct/rct/Log.h:17,
                 from /home/mark/Downloads/rtags-2.38/src/rct/rct/AES256CBC.cpp:10:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-37/include/linux/cache.h:6:10: fatal error: asm/cache.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <asm/cache.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/rct.dir/build.make:63: src/CMakeFiles/rct.dir/rct/rct/AES256CBC.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1013: src/CMakeFiles/rct.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

As I interpret it there seems to be a missing link between the cmake setup and the CPU architecture because there is:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-37/arch/arm64/include/asm/cache.h
```

I couldn't find a way to tell cmake that I want a build for amd64 - or do I need to tell this to make?

The installed kernel headers are:

```
Package: linux-aws-headers-5.4.0-1009
Package: linux-azure-headers-5.4.0-1010
Package: linux-gcp-headers-5.4.0-1009
Package: linux-kvm-headers-5.4.0-1009
Package: linux-oracle-headers-5.4.0-1009
Package: linux-oem-5.6-headers-5.6.0-1007
Package: linux-riscv-headers-5.4.0-24
Package: linux-aws-headers-5.4.0-1011
Package: linux-aws-headers-5.4.0-1015
Package: linux-azure-headers-5.4.0-1012
Package: linux-azure-headers-5.4.0-1016
Package: linux-gcp-headers-5.4.0-1011
Package: linux-gcp-headers-5.4.0-1015
Package: linux-kvm-headers-5.4.0-1011
Package: linux-oracle-headers-5.4.0-1011
Package: linux-kvm-headers-5.4.0-1015
Package: linux-oracle-headers-5.4.0-1015
Package: linux-oem-5.6-headers-5.6.0-1008
Package: linux-oem-5.6-headers-5.6.0-1010
Package: linux-oem-5.6-headers-5.6.0-1011
Package: linux-riscv-headers-5.4.0-26
Package: linux-riscv-headers-5.4.0-27
```

Comment: Seems like some path problem. Try to add `include_directory` with the path where the `asm/cache.h` is placed.

Comment: I am not sure whether setting `ZLIB_LIBRARY` to `lmzlibw.so` is correct or not, but setting `ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR` to `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-37/include/` is definitely wrong: this directory contains headers for the **Linux kernel**, they should never been used for user space applications.

Comment: @Tsyvarev those were the only places where I found parts of ZLIB. I installed the dev version but didn't understand how it integrated into the system. The headers should be in /usr/include/zlib or something, no?

Comment: "I installed the dev version" - you may check which exact files you have installed with the package, and find out which include directory you need. Also, CMake normally detects packages, installed by package manager, without help.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Hm, it looks like this project is somehow unusable for casual Linux users :(

Comment: If you install [zlib1g-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/xenial/amd64/zlib1g-dev/filelist) package, then you should have `/usr/include/zlib.h` and this header should be detected by CMake without a help. The same is about the library file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a`.